# Refactoring Methods With Conditionals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have always suffered with too many conditionals in some of my methods. The following is a pseudocode/skeleton of one of my method like that:

```
private List<ReturnType> DoSth(string name = null)
{
    List<ReturnType> names = new List<ReturnType>();

    for (int i = 0; i < somearray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (somecondition)
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                //'Add' to list
            }
            else
            {
                if (someothercondition)
                {
                    //'Add' to list 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return names;
}
```

Actual Code which returns an object filled with Controller and corresponding Action names:

```
private List<AppController> GetControllerActions(string ControllerName = null)
{
    Type[] typelist = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "Project.Web.Controllers", StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();

    List<AppController> names = new List<AppController>();

    for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
    {
        if (typelist[i].BaseType.Name == "Controller")
        {
            if (ControllerName == null)
            {
                names.Add(new AppController
                {
                    ControllerName = typelist[i].Name,
                    ActionName = typelist[i].GetMethods()
                    .Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
                    .Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
                }); 
            }
            else
            {
                if (typelist[i].Name == ControllerName)
                {
                    names.Add(new AppController
                    {
                        ControllerName = typelist[i].Name,
                        ActionName = typelist[i].GetMethods()
                        .Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
                        .Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
                    }); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return names;
}
```

As you can see the same `Add` code is being repeated twice and the 'Add' code is not an external method and I would prefer not making it one also. I can also provide the actual code if required.

*Is there any scope of making this code more concise and compact like you can do with ternary operators for example?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just combine the logic into one statement, assuming there is not other things occurring during your if-else blocks and stuff.
If there is, then this won't necessarily work for you, and you should post the real code, because a lot of times these problems are subjective to the code.

I guess one lesson to possibly learn from this is just to realize the end result, and build a condition that matches the necessary conditions to do something.

```
if (somecondition && (name == null || someothercondition))
{
    //'Add' to list
}
```

**Edit**: To expand upon the OPs full code being posted.

My original answer is still valid you would write it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
{
    if (typelist[i].BaseType.Name == "Controller" && (ControllerName == null || typelist[i].Name == ControllerName))
    names.Add(new AppController
    {
        ControllerName = typelist[i].Name,
        ActionName = typelist[i].GetMethods()
        .Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
        .Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
    }); 
}
```

However, now that you have actual code to review, I will also point out that there is no reason to be using a `for` loop vs a `foreach` loop. I would write that as follows.

```
foreach (var t in typelist)
{
    if (t.BaseType.Name == "Controller" && (ControllerName == null || t.Name == ControllerName))
    names.Add(new AppController
    {
        ControllerName = t.Name,
        ActionName = t.GetMethods()
        .Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
        .Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
    }); 
}
```

At this point I am recognizing that we are iterating through a list, and conditionally doing one thing. This appears to be the perfect candidate for using some linq.

using Where and some lambda we can make this statement to return an `IEnumerable<Type>` which only contains Types we need to add.

```
typelist.Where(t => t.BaseType.Name == "Controller" && (ControllerName == null || t.Name == ControllerName))
```

On our newly created `IEnumerable<Type>` we can Select what we want to add to the names list.

```
.Select(t => new AppController
{
    ControllerName = t.Name,
    ActionName = t.GetMethods()
    .Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
    .Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
});
```

Now if this was a time where names was an existing list we only needed to append to we could use `names.AddRange()` but because this list was created here for this purpose (I think).
we can just ToList() our results and save them as the list.

At this point you could have a few different variables, or you could make your code look awesome and confusing and one-line it all. because I see now that typelist is only being referenced once. (Btw it should probably named typeList, with a capital L, but we're getting rid of it anyway).

So in the very end you can have this beautiful chunk of code. Note: I am also going to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of just checking if it is null.

```
private List<AppController> GetControllerActions(string ControllerName = null)
{
    return
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "Project.Web.Controllers", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        .Where(t => t.BaseType.Name == "Controller" && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ControllerName) || t.Name == ControllerName))
        .Select(t => new AppController
        {
            ControllerName = t.Name,
            ActionName = t.GetMethods()
            .Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
            .Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have posted the actual code above.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim with your updated code it looks like my answer still stands as valid.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim I have updated my post again to use linq and one-line the entire method

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can guess you are trying to test whether some method returns a subclass of `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult` repeated snippet here:

```
w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult")
```

But this snippet fails in three cases:

1. If a class inherits from a `ActionResult` indirectly. e.g.

   ```
   class Y: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult {}
   class X: Y {}
   typeof(X).BaseType.Name != "ActionResult"
   ```
2. If a class is not a subclass of `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult` but happens to be named `ActionResult` e.g. `Some.Unrelated.Name.Space.ActionResult`. e.g.

   ```
   var t1 = typeof(Some.Unrelated.Name.Space.ActionResult);
   var t2 = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult);
   t1.Name == t2.Name;
   t1 != t2;
   ```
3. If a class is not a subclass of `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult` but happens to directly inherit from a class named `ActionResult` e.g.

   ```
   class X:Some.Unrelated.Name.Space.ActionResult {}
   typeof(X).BaseType.Name == "ActionResult"
   // but 
   typeof(X).BaseType != typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)
   ```

What you actually want is [`Type.IsAssignable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx). So:

```
.Where(w => w.ReturnType.BaseType != null && (w.ReturnType.BaseType.Name == "ActionResult" || w.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult"))
```

should become:

```
.Where(method => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult).IsAssignable(method.ReturnType)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Actually I was trying to detect only methods with return type as `ActionResult` or any type **directly** inheriting from `ActionResult`. Your point no. 2 and 3 is definitely correct in my case though.